# "Not a lot of his friends..."

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, quantifiers

I have come across the following construction, but l am not sure whether it is correct or not.

> Not a lot of his friends speak English well.

My question is: can we use "a lot of" in a negative sentence as mentioned above?

Comment: Sure, but "*not many of* his friends" would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use this construction. From the Merriam-Webster dictionary:

> Definition of ***a lot of***
>
> a large number or amount of (things, people, etc.)
>
> *A lot of people feel that way.*
>   *There was a lot of space.*
>   *Not a lot of people know that.*
>
> Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20lot%20of

I think it's fine for informal usage, but I personally would avoid using it in formal, written English. The word ***lot***, defined as ***a large number or amount***, often carries the "informal" label in dictionaries. ***Not a lot of*** seems even more informal to me.

Comment: You are right. My first impression was that it was not appropriate to use in a formal context. Anyway l appreciate your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

As Ringo has said, you can most certainly use this within this sentence however it is more informal. A more formal alternative would be to say *"not **many** of his friends speak English well"*.